# Opening new tab with URL from link element in active tab using Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create an extension that will open a new tab in chrome with the URL of a link element in the active tab. I've added the permissions for background, tabs and activeTab in my manifest file. I know I can use

```
chrome.tabs.create({ url: newURL });
```

My issue is that the background.js file can't access elements on the active tab (or at least I haven't been able to access them). Is there a way to give the background file access to variables within a content script, or direct access to the DOM of the active tab?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to give the background file access to variables within a content script, or direct access to the DOM of the active tab?

No, and no. Privileged pages are isolated from content scripts for security reasons.

You need to use Messaging for it, e.g. [send a message](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#simple) `{action: "openURL", url: newURL}` and process it in the background.